# How to disable the modal view when clicking on a lookup field?

Tags: list-view-web-part

I have a "Parent" list and a "Child" list, linked by a lookup column.

Both lists have "Show in modal dialog" disabled.

On the home page, I have a listview web part that displays the "Child" list, with some fields including the lookup to parent column.

When I click on this column, it shows me the parent item, but in a modal dialog.

How can I avoid this modal dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by editing xslt in spd, namely you should change `<xsl:value-of select>` tag and add the surrounding `<a>`

```
<a href="http://vxmc2170345/Lists/facilty/DispForm.aspx?ID={substring-after($thisNode/@IDofListX., '#')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($thisNode/@IDofListX. , '#')"/> </a>
```

more detail: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/5eec99a9-abd7-45c9-9d11-9eae5062851b

Comment: Hi @Ksesh and welcome to our forum. Please dont just post a url to another forum. Use a few lines to explain what kind of solution we might find there, and *then* link to the post. External urls tend to be short lived, and we plan to stay around for a while ;-)

Comment: I was looking for a way to avoid xsl. I will fall back to this solution if it's the only one, but I hope there will be a click/click/click solution.